# How to sort a list of files based on version number in the end of the file name

Tags: python

I have a list of files mapped as following:

```
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

[
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.5', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.2', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.3', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.4', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.10', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.1', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.6', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.7', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log'
]
```

When I try to sort it with `files.sort()` I get this:

```
[
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.1', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.10', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.2', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.3', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.4', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.5', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.6', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.7'
]
```

Notice that the file **MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.10** is in the 3rd position of the list.

How to sort this list properly so it is in correct sequence?

```
[
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.1', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.2', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.3', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.4', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.5', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.6', 
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.7',
'MESSAGEHUB_INGEST.log.10', 
]
```

Comment: Yes, it did the trick! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:
Using regexp to extract the number following the word log in each entry. If `re.findall` returns an empty list, then `return -1`, so that it gets the topmost priority in the sorted list.

```
import re
def fun(x):
    li = re.findall(r'.log.([0-9]*)',x)
    if li:
        return int(li[0])
    else:
        return -1

print(sorted(li,key= lambda x: fun(x)))
```

Comment: can the user tell me, what's wrong with the approach and why was it downvoted?

Comment: Could you explain a little more about this snippet? I tried to apply it, but it did not work (btw, I did not downvoted it).

Comment: There is NameError in the code. I've corrected it now! I'm using regexp to find out the number after the word `.log.num` & using it as a key to sort the entries. If incase there is no number, an empty list is returned. All such entries will be placed on the beginning of the sorted list.